# Connecting Piwik front-end (App server) to remote MySQL server with SSL support

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, matomo

I am trying to install Piwik on a VPS and connect it to a MySQL database on another (remote) VPS.

The first problem: I don't actually know how to connect Piwik to remote MySql server with self-signed SSL.

So, I've tried to make the user without required SSL connection to try to get Piwik installation to working. I've got the following error: **SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user '****'@'******' (using password: YES)**

(Screenshot of the error: http://bit.ly/1FhrnHY)

User have all appropriate privileges to connect successfully, but it doesn't connect.

1. I've successfully tried to connect via command line MySql client
   with SSL support.
2. MySql with SSL has been configured properly (and
   tried from command line).

My questions are:

1. How to resolve that problem (an error) to get connected to remote MySQL database for using with my Piwik installation?
2. How to connect to the remote database with self-signed SSL support (from Piwik)?

Answer (score 0):

Support for Mysql SSL connections is now being proposed in a Pull Request on Piwik github: https://github.com/piwik/piwik/pull/8049 - feel free to test it and report your feedback.